# Can't send ajax headers from js script

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have build an API. It listens in port 8000 and my app is listening on port 3000.

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:8000/communities",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "authorization": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiWVx1MDBlMWJpciIsImFkbWluIjp0cnVlfQ.xtvKyxq26b7K02mVv21vkt7PbeOUatMbgxLOHIj7CQg",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    });
});
```

I know it is not problem of some set-up because desactivating token auth in server I get the data. This code was generated from PostMan chrome app but when making the query from my js file I get a 401 Error and from the server I can see the `authorization` header has not been set. What could be the problem?

In the chrome console appears:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Headers received by the server from localhost:3000

```
{'ACCEPT': '*/*', 'ACCESS-CONTROL-REQUEST-METHOD': 'GET', 'CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'ACCEPT-ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br', 'HOST': 'localhost:8000', 'REFERER': 'http://localhost:3000/', 'USER-AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/55.0.2883.87 Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36', 'ORIGIN': 'http://localhost:3000', 'ACCESS-CONTROL-REQUEST-HEADERS': 'authorization, cache-control, 'ACCEPT-LANGUAGE': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8'}
```

And from PostMan

```
{'AUTHORIZATION': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjoiWVx1MDBlMWJpciIsImFkbWluIjp0cnVlfQ.xtvKyxq26b7K02mVv21vkt7PbeOUatMbgxLOHIj7CQg', 'ACCEPT': '*/*', 'CACHE-CONTROL': 'no-cache', 'POSTMAN-TOKEN': '06aba643-b6cb-3a7a-9e6e-61b1f2d9e94e', 'CONNECTION': 'keep-alive', 'ACCEPT-ENCODING': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br', 'HOST': 'localhost:8000', 'USER-AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/55.0.2883.87 Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36', 'ACCEPT-LANGUAGE': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8'}
```

PD: Also server setup allows CORS.

Comment: Odds are that you've failed to take into account the need to handle a pre-flight options request … but you haven't quoted the error messages from the Console or the complete request from the Network tab, so it is hard to say for sure.

Comment: how are you handling your oauth flow?

Comment: @Quentin Added message from chrome Console and the headers received by the server.

Comment: @YábirGarcia — What request method is it? Those headers do suggest it is a preflight OPTIONS request which you aren't handling (or reproducing with PostMan)

Comment: @Quentin It accepts both GET and POST. In this case I'm trying a GET

Comment: @YábirGarcia — But the browser has to make a preflight OPTIONS first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It accepts both GET and POST. In this case I'm trying a GET

Since you are not making a simple request (you're adding HTTP headers), the browser makes a [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) to ask for permission to make the GET request with extra request headers.

The server is rejecting that OPTIONS request as unauthorised and the browser is refusing to make the GET request.

You need to write server side code to handle the OPTIONS request.